# Info on Scrapy CONCURRENT_REQUESTS

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy and I read on the doc about the setting "CONCURRENT_REQUESTS". The docs talk about "The maximum number of concurrent (ie. simultaneous) requests that will be performed by the Scrapy downloader."

I created a spider in order to take questions and answers from Q&A websites, so I want to know if is possible run multiple concurrent requests.
Now I have set this value to 1 because I don't want to lose some Item or override someone.

The **main doubt** is that I have a Global ID `idQuestion` (for making an `idQuestion.idAnswer`) for any item so I don't know if making multiple requests all can be a mess and lose some Item or set wrong Ids.

This is a snippet of code:

```
class Scraper(scrapy.Spider):
    uid = 1


    def parse_page(self, response):
        # Scraping a single question

        item = ScrapeItem()
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        #item['date_time'] = response.meta['data']
        item['type'] = "Question"
        item['uid'] = str(self.uid)
        item['url'] = response.url

        #Do some scraping.
        ans_uid = ans_uid + 1
        item['uid'] = str(str(self.uid) + (":" + str(ans_uid)))
        yield item

        #Call recusivly the method on other page.
        print("NEXT -> "+str(composed_string))
        yield scrapy.Request(composed_string, callback=self.parse_page)
```

This is the skeleton of my code.
I use uid to memorize the id for the single question and ans_uid for the answer.

Ex:

1. Question

1.1) Ans 1 for Question 1

1.2) Ans 2 for Question 1

1.3) Ans 3 for Question 1

**Can I simply increase the CONCURRENT_REQUESTS value without compromising anything?**

Comment: `ans_uid` is not initialized

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is: **no**. If you increase the concurrent requests you can end up having different values for `uid` -- even if the question is the same later. That's because there is no guarantee that your requests are handled in order.

However you can pass information along your `Request` objects with the `meta` attribute. I would pass along the ID with the `yield Request(...`  as a meta tag and then look in the `parse_page` if this attribute is available or not. If it is not then it is a new question, if yes, use this id because this is not a new question.

You can read more about `meta` here: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta

Answer (score 0):

Scrapy is **not a multithreaded environment**, but rather uses an **event loop driven asynchronous architecture** (Twisted, which is **a bit like node.js for python**).

**in that sense, it is completely thread safe.**

You actually have a reference to the request object as response -> response.request, which has response.request.url, as well as the referer header sent, and response.request.meta so you have mapping from answers back to questions built in. (like a referrer header of sorts) if you are reading from a list of questions or answers from a single page, you are guaranteed that those questions and answers will be read in order.

you can do something like the following:

```
class mySpider(Spider):
    def parse_answer(self, response):
        question_url = response.request.headers.get('Referer', None)
        yield Answer(question_url = ..., answerinfo = ... )

class Answer(item):
    answer = ....
    question_url = ...
```

Hope that helps.